# multiple session files are created on each request in laravel 5.2.*

Tags: php, laravel, session

Currently I'm working with laravel 5.2.29. On each request new session file is generated and the old file is not deleted.

config/session.php file

```
<?php
return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,
    'http_only' => true,
];
```

I put all routes inside middleware group 'web'

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //Login
    Route::post('login', 'User\LoginController@login'); 
});
```

Why this happens? How to solve this problem?

I have tried with changing the cookie name, previuosly in laravel 5.2.23 it works fine so I downgrade the project to laravel 5.2.23 and tried But not working.

Someone help me out to solve this.

Comment: As of Laravel 5.2.27 the web middleware is now in place by default, https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.27/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L56. Try removing the `Route::group` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Route::group and that should remove the duplicates. As for the old session files, it will be cleaned up after some time. Just leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

after the upgrade from 5.1 to laravel 5.4 I had a similar issue, I found that I didn't upgraded app/Http/Kernel.php correctly.

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
```

was declared twice in `protected $middleware` array and in

```
protected $middlewareGroups
```

after removing it from `$middleware` array it started to work correctly

`$middleware` applied to all routes and `$middlewareGroups` applied to specific groups